# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]}{x^n}\, dx = 0$. Where $\int$ represents Lebesgue integration.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

Please check my proof, thank you.

---

Prove
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]}{x^n}\, dx = 0
\end{align*}
***Proof***. Let $f_n(x) = x^n$. Since $f_n$ is a polynomial it is continuous and therefore measurable. It is clear that $(x^n) \to 0$ for $x \in [0, 1)$ and $(x)^n \to 1$ for $x = 1$. Furthermore, $0 \leq x^{n+1} \leq x^{n}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. So, $f_n$ is measurable, nonnegative, and decreasing, and $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$. By the <s>monotone</s> dominated convergence theorem
\begin{align}
    \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]}{x^n}\, dx  = \int_{[0,1]}{0}\, dx  = 0 \cdot m{[0,1]} = 0
\end{align}

---

Edit. So apparently the monotone convergence theorem applies to only *increasing* sequences of functions. So for the problem above we could let $g_n(x) = x - x^n$. Now $(g_n)$ is an monotone increasing sequence that is nonnegative and measurable (continuous). Also $(g_n) \to x$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$ (not at $x = 1$). So by the monotone convergence theorem

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]}{g_n(x)}\, dx  = \int_{[0,1]}{x}\, dx = \int_{[0,1]}\left(f_1(x) - 0\right) \, dx
\end{align}

also we have

\begin{align}
f_1(x) &= \left(x - x^k\right) + x^k \\ \\
&\implies \int_{[0,1]}x = \int_{[0,1]} \left(x - x^k\right) + \int_{[0,1]} x^k
\\ \\
&\implies \left(\int_{[0,1]}x\right) - \left(\int_{[0,1]} x^k\right) = \int_{[0,1]} \left(x - x^k\right)
\\ \\
&\implies \lim_{k \to \infty} \left[ \left(\int_{[0,1]}x\right) -\left(\int_{[0,1]} x^k\right) \right] = \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} \left(x - x^k\right) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} g_k(x)
\\ \\
&\implies \left(\int_{[0,1]}x\right) - \lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\int_{[0,1]} x^k\right) =  \left(\int_{[0,1]} x\right)
\\ \\
&\implies - \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} x^k =  0
\\ \\
&\implies \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} x^k =  0
\end{align}

Comment: I think MCT applies to monotone increasing sequences. But you can use DCT for the same result.

Comment: Why not just compute the integral and then take the limit?

Comment: How do you compute the lebesgue integral of $x^n$?

Comment: By noting that it's the same as the Riemann integral. Unless you don't have that theorem then just use dominated convergence like user25959 said.

Comment: @user25959 you can apply also MCT here without much effort, taking $g_n(x):=-f_n(x)+1$ and $g(x):=-f(x)+1$, and after applying elementary properties of the Lebesgue integral

Comment: If $a,b\in \Bbb R$ with$ a<b$ and if $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ is continuous then the Lebesgue integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx $ is equal to the classical integral. Riemann integration and Lebesgue integration were developed in order to extend integration to much larger classes of functions.